# family of pairwise disjoint sets in the complement of meager. set

Tags: set-theory, transfinite-recursion, transfinite-induction

Let $M$ be a meager subset of $\mathbb R$. I want to construct the following family in $\mathbb R\setminus M $
$$F:= \{A_{r}^\xi\colon r\in\mathbb R \ \&\ \xi<c\}$$ Such that all elemnets of $F$ are pairwise disjoint dense sets and $\bigcup F$does not contain any perfect sets. I want to try to construct by using transfinite induction. My first challenge is how can I do the transfinite induction for $r$ and $\xi$. If they are two ordinal number like $A_{\xi}^{\eta}$ then we can define well ordering like $\leq$ on $c\times c$ ($c$ is the cardinality of $\mathbb R$ by putting $<\alpha,\beta>\leq<\gamma,\delta>$ if and only if $$max\{\alpha,\beta\}=\{\gamma,\delta\}$$ OR $$max\{\alpha,\beta\}<\{\gamma,\delta\}\ and \ \alpha=\gamma \  \ OR \ \ max\{\alpha,\beta\}<\{\gamma,\delta\}, \ \alpha<\gamma, \ and \ \beta=\delta.$$ But in my case I have $r\in\mathbb R.$ What should I do? My thought process for the  proof is enumerate all open intervals and all perfect sets which there are continuum many of them and construct by picking one element of each open interval and avoid element of perfect set at the same time. but the challenge when I reach the inductive step I have no control how can I keep the pairwise disjoint since I am doing this proof in ZFC. I like transfinite  induction but sometimes is challenging for me. Any hint or idea how this can be done it will be useful. Thank you in advance

Comment: In the way that you post the question, there is no a important meaning over the indexs. So, you can build the family with indexs in $\mathfrak{c}$ and then, reenumerate with a bijection between $\mathfrak{c}\times\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Significantly revised to correct an oversight and for greater clarity.**

Let $\mathscr{B}$ be a base for $\Bbb R\setminus M$, let $\mathscr{C}$ be the family of uncountable closed subsets of $\Bbb R\setminus M$, and let $\mathscr{S}=\mathscr{B}\cup\mathscr{C}$; note that $\mathscr{C}$ contains all of the perfect subsets of $\Bbb R\setminus M$. Let $T=\Bbb R\times\mathscr{S}\times\mathfrak{c}$; $|T|=\mathfrak{c}$, so we can index $T$ as $T=\{\langle r_\xi,S_\xi,\alpha_\xi\rangle:\xi<\mathfrak{c}\}$. Now you can construct your sets $A_r^\alpha$ by straightforward transfinite recursion on $\xi<\mathfrak{c}$.

> (**Note:** Transfinite **induction** is a proof technique: what you’re doing here is transfinite **recursion**.)

Suppose that $\eta<\mathfrak{c}$, and you’ve already chosen points $x_\xi,y_\xi\in S_\xi$ for $\xi<\eta$ so that all of these points are distinct. You’ve chosen fewer than $\mathfrak{c}$ points, and $|S_\eta|=\mathfrak{c}$, so you can choose distinct

$$x_\eta,y_\eta\in S_\eta\setminus\big(\{x_\xi:\xi<\eta\}\cup\{y_\xi:\xi<\eta\}\big)$$

and continue the recursion. (You do need to know here that every member of $\mathscr{S}$ has cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$.)

Now for each $\langle r,\eta\rangle\in\Bbb R\times\mathfrak{c}$ let $A_r^\alpha=\{x_\xi:r_\xi=r\text{ and }\alpha_\xi=\alpha\}$.

- For each $B\in\mathscr{B}$ there is a $\xi<\mathfrak{c}$ such that $\langle r_\xi,S_\xi,\alpha_\xi\rangle=\langle r,B,\alpha\rangle$, and $x_\xi\in A_r^\alpha\cap B$, so $A_r^\alpha$ is dense in $\Bbb R\setminus M$.
- For each $C\in\mathscr{C}$ there is a $\xi<\mathfrak{c}$ such that $\langle r_\xi,S_\xi,\alpha_\xi\rangle=\langle r,C,\alpha\rangle$; by construction $x_\xi\in A_r^\alpha\cap C$ and $y_\xi\in C\setminus A_r^\alpha$, so $A_r^\alpha$ is a Bernstein set and contains no perfect set.
- The points $x_\xi$ for $\xi<\mathfrak{c}$ are all distinct, so $\{A_r^\alpha:\langle r,\alpha\rangle\in\Bbb R\times\mathfrak{c}\}$ is a pairwise disjoint family.

Comment: Brian M, ignore my last comment. I hope you can explain this for me. In the construction, you just did $A_{r}^\xi$. Two, I have how can Ii construct the rest? and how can I keep them pairwise disjoint ? Also, how make the union of all A's does not contain any perfect set ?  since I struggle with these  questions a lot when I was thinking how to do the proof. Thank you again

Comment: @00GB: No, I constructed an $A_r^\xi$ for each $\langle r,\xi\rangle\in\Bbb R\times\mathfrak{c}$, and I constructed them to be disjoint, because all of the points $x_\eta$ are distinct. I also ensured that their union does not contain a perfect set, because none of the points $y_\eta$ are in their union, and every perfect set contains one of those points.

Comment: could you please see by word how do you think about the definition of $A_{r}^\xi$? I have some difficulties to understand it. Thank you again

Comment: @00GB: For each $\eta<\mathfrak{c}$ we have a point $x_\eta$; all of these points are distinct. For each $n\in\omega$ and $\beta<\mathfrak{c}$ there is an $\eta<\mathfrak{c}$ such that $r_\eta=r$, $n_\eta=n$, $\beta_\eta=\beta$, and $\gamma_\eta=\xi$, and $x_\eta\in A_r^\xi$ for each of those $\eta$s, so $|A_r^\xi|=|\omega\times\mathfrak{c}|=\mathfrak{c}$. When $\beta_\eta=n$, $x_\eta\in B_n$, so $A_r^\xi$ is dense. And when $\beta_\eta=\beta$, $y_\eta\in P_\eta\setminus A_r^\xi$, so $A_r^\xi\nsupseteq P_\eta$. Thus, $A_r^\xi$ does not contain any perfect set.

Comment: @Brain, I just realized this argument would not work as it is because you have no control for $B_{n_\eta}\cap P_{\beta_\eta}\setminus M$ to be nonempty since $M$ might be Cantor set for example unless you can prove this can not happen.

Comment: @00GB: Yes, that was an oversight. It’s fairly easy to repair, but it will take some time to write up clearly, and I probably won’t get to it until later tonight.

Comment: Brian. one way to fix you have to choose $x_\eta$ and $y_\eta$ chosen from different sets to avoid this issue. if You can construct  $A^\xi_r$ to be Bernstein set in $\mathbb R$ this would be great

Comment: @00GB: No, in general I’m going to need to choose $x_\eta$ and $y_\eta$ from the same set. However, I think that I can fairly easily ensure that the sets $A_r^\xi$ are Bernstein sets.

Comment: @Brain, It might be in one case the make condition in lemma weaker, that is, the union of all $A^xi_r$ does not contain any perfect from $\mathbb R\setminus M.$  Otherwise the same issue still exits

Comment: @00GB: I’m sorry that it took me so long to get to this, but I think that in addition to correcting the oversights in the original version, I’ve also made it a bit clearer.

Comment: Thank you again for your time. By Bernstein set, you mean Bernstein set in $\mathbb R\setminus M$. in your inductive set $$x_\eta,y_\eta\in S_\eta\setminus\big(\{x_\xi:\xi<\eta\}\cup\{y_\xi:\xi<\eta\}\big)$$  are you fix $S_{\eta}$ and how you make sure all $x_{\xi}$ are distinct.

Comment: @00GB: Yes, I’m working entirely in $\Bbb R\setminus M$. It’s implicit in the enumeration of $T$ that we have an enumeration $\mathscr{S}=\{S_\xi:\xi<\mathfrak{c}\}$ of $\mathscr{S}$; $S_\eta$ is simply the $\eta$-th set in this enumeration. The $x_\xi$ are distinct because at each stage we choose $x_\xi$ and $y_\xi$ to be distinct from all of the ones chosen earlier.

Comment: @Brain, sorry for asking so many questions. But you did not ensure that the union of all $A^\alpha_r$ does not contain any perfect set since the union of all Bernstein sets might  contain perfect set

Comment: @00GB: On the contrary, the union of the sets $A_r^\alpha$ cannot contain any perfect set, because every perfect set contains one of the points $y_\xi$, and the points $y_\xi$ are not in any of the sets $A_r^\alpha$.

Comment: Brian . Sorry I just checked again do you mean that $\mathscr{S}$ contains all perfect set Not $\mathscr{C}$ Right? If so, I think it is clear but I would like to hear your reason why this $\mathscr{S}$ contains all perfect set.

Comment: @00GB: Every perfect subset of $\Bbb R\setminus M$ is uncountable and closed, so it’s a member of $\mathscr{C}$. $\mathscr{S}=\mathscr{B}\cup\mathscr{C}$, so it’s also a member of $\mathscr{S}$.